Why is my Next.js 14 Middleware not receiving refreshToken cookies set by my backend
Question:
I am using Next.js 14 with the App Router to build an application that requires authentication. I have implemented a middleware to protect certain routes and check for a valid refreshToken stored in cookies. However, the refreshToken cookie is not available in the middleware, even though it is set correctly by my backend after login.
Here is a summary of my setup:
Backend Setup (Node.js/Express)
I am using Express on the backend to handle authentication. After a successful login, I set the refreshToken cookie like this:
const { loginService } = require('../services/authService');

const loginController = async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    console.log(`Extracted username: ${username}, password: ${password}`);

    try {
        const { accessToken, refreshToken } = await loginService(username, password);

        // Return access token in response instead of setting it as a cookie
        res.status(200).cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: true,
            sameSite: 'Lax', // Ensure secure cookies in production
            maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 7 days
            path: '/', // Ensure the cookie is set for the entire domain
        }).json({
            message: 'Login successful',
            accessToken // Include accessToken in the response
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Authentication failed',
            error: error.message,
        });
    }
};

module.exports = {
    loginController,
};

Middleware Setup (Next.js 14)
The middleware checks for the presence of the refreshToken cookie to determine if the user is authenticated:

// middleware.js (Next.js 14 App Router)

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import axios from 'axios';

export async function middleware(request) {
const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;

console.log('Middleware triggered on path:', pathname);

// Allow access to static assets and Next.js internal files
if (
pathname.startsWith('/\_next/') ||
pathname.startsWith('/static/') ||
pathname.startsWith('/api/') ||
pathname.includes('.')
) {
console.log('Static asset or API route requested, allowing access...');
return NextResponse.next();
}

// List of public routes that do not require authentication
const publicRoutes = \['/login', '/'\]; // Add other public routes as needed

// Allow access to public routes without checking for the refresh token
if (publicRoutes.includes(pathname)) {
console.log('Accessing public route:', pathname);
return NextResponse.next();
}

// Check for the presence of the refresh token for non-public routes
const refreshToken = request.cookies.get('refreshToken')?.value; // Ensure 'refreshToken' matches the exact name
console.log('Refresh token found in cookies:', refreshToken); // Debugging log to verify if the token is found

if (!refreshToken) {
console.log('No refresh token found in cookies. Redirecting to login...');
return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url));
}

// Function to verify the refresh token by calling the backend API
const isRefreshTokenValid = async () =\> {
console.log('Verifying refresh token with API...');
try {
const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/refresh-token', {}, { withCredentials: true });
console.log('Refresh token verification response status:', response.status);
return response.status === 200; // Assuming a valid token returns a 200 status
} catch (error) {
console.error('Error verifying refresh token:', error.message);
return false; // Invalid or expired token
}
};

const isValid = await isRefreshTokenValid();
console.log('Is refresh token valid:', isValid);

if (!isValid) {
console.log('Invalid or expired refresh token, redirecting to login...');
return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url));
}

console.log('User authenticated, allowing access to:', pathname);
return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
matcher: \['/(.\*)'\],
};

Problem
When a user logs in, the backend sets the refreshToken cookie correctly (verified with Postman), but in my Next.js middleware, request.cookies.get('refreshToken') always returns undefined.
Questions
1. Why is the refreshToken cookie not available in the Next.js 14 middleware when it is set correctly by the backend?
2. How can I ensure the middleware correctly receives and handles cookies set by the backend?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
What I’ve Tried

Verified Cookie is Set Correctly: The Set-Cookie header appears correctly in the login response with HttpOnly, Secure, SameSite=Strict, and Path=/. played with all the variations

Checked Frontend Requests: All frontend requests use withCredentials: true to ensure cookies are sent.

Tested Direct API Calls: Direct API calls to protected routes using tools like Postman show the cookie is being sent.

Allowed Static Assets and Public Routes: I already allow static files and public routes to be accessed without checking for cookies.


